# Issues in implementing Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the 10th problem in project euler in which we are supposed to find the sum of all the prime numbers below 2 million. I am using Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm to find the prime numbers. Now I am facing and performance issue with the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm.

The performance goes down by a substantial amount if the `print(i,"",sum_of_prime)` is kept inside the loop. Is there anyway to see it working and keep the performance? If this is done with the conventional method it take some 13 minutes to get the result.

```
#Euler 10

#Problem:
#The sum of the primes below 10 is 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17.
#Find the sum of all the primes below two million.

#Author: Kshithij Iyer
#Date of creation: 15/1/2017

import time
#Recording start time of the program
start=time.time()
def sum_of_prime_numbers(limit):
    "A function to get the sum prime numbers till the limit"
    #Variable to store the sum of prime numbers
    sum_of_prime=0
    #Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm
    sieve=[True]*limit
    for i in range(2,limit):
        if sieve[i]:
            sum_of_prime=sum_of_prime+i
            for j in range(i*i,limit,i):
                sieve[j]=False
            print(i,"",sum_of_prime)
    print("The sum of all the prime numbers below",limit,"is",sum_of_prime)
    return
#sum_of_prime_numbers(10)
sum_of_prime_numbers(2000001)
print("Execution time of program is",time.time()-start)

#Note:
#I did give the conventioanl method a try but it didn't work well and was taking
#some 13 minutes to get the results.

#Algorithm for reference
#Input: an integer n > 1

#Let A be an array of Boolean values, indexed by integers 2 to n,
#initially all set to true.

#for i = 2, 3, 4, ..., not exceeding √n:
#if A[i] is true:
#for j = i2, i2+i, i2+2i, i2+3i, ..., not exceeding n :
#A[j] := false

#Output: all i such that A[i] is true.
```

Comment: Try to populate the array with primes first then calculate the sum. Try and tell me ?

Comment: I have rephrased the question please read it and share your views on it.

Comment: You could reduce the amount of printing done with something like: `if not (i % 10): print(i,"",sum_of_prime)` in the inner loop.

Comment: You could also have some kind of progress bar. See question [_Script to show progress?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520622/python-script-to-show-progress)

Comment: The only issue with progress bar is that it doesn't give a clear picture of what is happening in the background. That's one reason why i was avoiding it.

Answer (score 0):

So there are various improvements that could be made here:

Firstly, due to the nature of Eratosthenes' sieve, you can replace `for i in range(2,limit):` with `for i in range(2,int(limit**0.5)+1):` and the array will be calculated normally, but much faster; however, as a result, you would then have to sum the numbers later.

Also, you are not going to be able to read every individual prime and nor would you want to; instead, you only need the program to tell you milestones, such as every time the program reaches a certain number to check everything against.

Your program does not appear to take into account the fact that arrays start at 0, which should certainly cause some problems; however, this should be fairly fixable.

Finally, it occurs to me that your program appears to count 1 as prime; this should be another easy fix though.

Comment: No the loop stats from 2 and one will never be taken into consideration please refer to the algorithm before speculating anything.

Comment: What I am saying is that to use my suggested (and much faster) method, you would have to make a couple of edits. While it does not currently appear in the output, the latter 2 problems would apply in my suggestion.